# I want to convert a column's datatype to int in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe and want to convert the type of the field 'User_total_Review' into the int datatype.

Here's the code I tried to use for this task:

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.astype({"User_total_Review": int})
```

but I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,'

I expected to get the column converted into int datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize string values before converting to `int` type:

```
df['User_total_Review'] = df['User_total_Review'].str.replace(r',\s*', '', regex=True)
df = df.astype({"User_total_Review": int})
```